# Is didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation deprecated?

Tags: ios, deprecated, screen-orientation, xcode8

I am trying to implement didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation method to notify orientation change but in iOS 10 and Xcode 8.1 it is showing like deprecate method.

[image]

Is it deprecated? If Yes then what are the replacements?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is deprecated since iOS 8. You should use [`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransitiontosize) instead.